# How to get info stored in the state of the store.js in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, getter-setter

I am developing my first application in vuejs.
It's a form with several steps that share a header and a footer and as I go along I send to the store.js the info I'm putting in each section.
I have been stuck for a couple of days in the fact that I am not able to retrieve the info from the first sections of the form to be able to show a summary of the info entered in the last step.
In each step every time I click on the advance button I send the info to store.js and I navigate to the next component.
This would be an example of the action in one of the components

```
      onSubmit() {
             
        const formData = {
            selectedService: this.focusService,
            selectedItem: this.selectedItem,
            selectedShop: this.selectedShop,
            selectedItemId: this.selectedItemId
          };
          this.$store.dispatch('formInfo', {
            selectedService: formData.selectedService,
            selectedItem: formData.selectedItem,
            selectedShop: formData.selectedShop,
            selectedItemId: formData.selectedItemId            
          });
          this.$store.dispatch('setStep', this.step + 1)
          this.$router.push('/shop/buyer')

      },
```

In the store.js I check that the info arrives correctly in the 'formInfo()' method and I save it in a declared state class property and I set up a get of the info stored in the state.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    step: 0,
    idToken: null,
    items: null,
    shops: null,
    estimations:null,

    owner: {
      ownerCivility: '',
      ownerLastname: '',
      ownerFirstname: '',
      ownerAddressFirstLine: '',
      ownerAddressSecondLine: '',
      ownerAddressThirdLine: '',
      ownerPostalCode: '',
      ownerCity: '',
      ownerPhone: '',
      ownerEmail: '',
      country: 'FR'
    },
    fisrtStepInfo: {

    }
  },
  actions: {
      formInfo({commit, dispatch}, authData) {
      console.log(authData)
      this.fisrtStepInfo = authData
      console.log(this.fisrtStepInfo)
    }

  },
  getters: {
    formInfoFirstStep (state) {
      console.log(state)
      return state.fisrtStepInfo
    }
  }
```

Finally, in the component where I want to show that info in my html, I set in the 'computed' section of my script the call to getter previously declared in the store.js.

```
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
              step: 2,
              civil: '',
              name: '',
              lastName: '',
              email: '',
              adresse: '',
              phone: '',
              postalCode: '',
              submitted: false,
            }
        },
        components:{
        },
        computed: {
            firstFormInfo() {
              console.log('firstforminfo')
              return !this.$store.getters.formInfoFirstStep
            },
        }
   }
</script>
```

But at this point, it doesn't even go through the getter in my 'computed' section.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Actions are similar to mutations, the differences being that: **Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.**

You need to `commit` a mutation instead of directly altering `state`:

```
  state: {
    ...
    fisrtStepInfo: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setStepInfo: (state, data) => state.fisrtStepInfo = data;
  }
  actions: {
    formInfo({commit, dispatch}, authData) {
      console.log(authData)
      commit('setStepInfo', authData)
      console.log(this.fisrtStepInfo)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    formInfoFirstStep (state) {
      console.log(state)
      return state.fisrtStepInfo
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely missed that step and then I was blocked from entering the component by the getter and I didn't realize I had deleted the reference in the html. 
It works perfectly, thanks again